# Python, dataframe, how to delete some values in a column, and add NaN, then combine the column with the existed table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is what my table looks like:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(60).reshape(20,3))
df.columns=['price','time','1-D']
```

Now, I want to add 9 more columns, which are '2-D', '3-D', ...., '10-D'.
The values in '2-D' are: 'NaN' plus all values in '1-D', but drop the last value (since I add a 'NaN' at first. Same to '3-D':'NaN'+ column['2-D'].

Here is the result I want to get:

```
Out[153]: 
       price      time       1-D       2-D       3-D       4-D       5-D  \
0   0.414901  0.173058  0.403901       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
1   0.918011  0.262294  0.641516  0.403901       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2   0.524934  0.051661  0.329890  0.641516  0.403901       NaN       NaN   
3   0.654412  0.867551  0.263398  0.329890  0.641516  0.403901       NaN   
4   0.107087  0.192514  0.598509  0.263398  0.329890  0.641516  0.403901   
5   0.232152  0.144453  0.107699  0.598509  0.263398  0.329890  0.641516   
6   0.105883  0.243597  0.602938  0.107699  0.598509  0.263398  0.329890   
7   0.269133  0.036553  0.749552  0.602938  0.107699  0.598509  0.263398   
8   0.144464  0.516613  0.179333  0.749552  0.602938  0.107699  0.598509   
9   0.901749  0.908061  0.025336  0.179333  0.749552  0.602938  0.107699   
10  0.247895  0.231501  0.157868  0.025336  0.179333  0.749552  0.602938   
11  0.132763  0.501174  0.171977  0.157868  0.025336  0.179333  0.749552   
12  0.165358  0.407833  0.284734  0.171977  0.157868  0.025336  0.179333   
13  0.960481  0.511533  0.249719  0.284734  0.171977  0.157868  0.025336   
14  0.016045  0.512287  0.206942  0.249719  0.284734  0.171977  0.157868   
15  0.948984  0.911282  0.269408  0.206942  0.249719  0.284734  0.171977   
16  0.470319  0.468252  0.289175  0.269408  0.206942  0.249719  0.284734   
17  0.751353  0.167094  0.531566  0.289175  0.269408  0.206942  0.249719   
18  0.854261  0.894898  0.513595  0.531566  0.289175  0.269408  0.206942   
19  0.016631  0.110026  0.797857  0.513595  0.531566  0.289175  0.269408   

         6-D       7-D       8-D       9-D      10-D  
0        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  
1        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  
2        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  
3        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  
4        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  
5   0.403901       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  
6   0.641516  0.403901       NaN       NaN       NaN  
7   0.329890  0.641516  0.403901       NaN       NaN  
8   0.263398  0.329890  0.641516  0.403901       NaN  
9   0.598509  0.263398  0.329890  0.641516  0.403901  
10  0.107699  0.598509  0.263398  0.329890  0.641516  
11  0.602938  0.107699  0.598509  0.263398  0.329890  
12  0.749552  0.602938  0.107699  0.598509  0.263398  
13  0.179333  0.749552  0.602938  0.107699  0.598509  
14  0.025336  0.179333  0.749552  0.602938  0.107699  
15  0.157868  0.025336  0.179333  0.749552  0.602938  
16  0.171977  0.157868  0.025336  0.179333  0.749552  
17  0.284734  0.171977  0.157868  0.025336  0.179333  
18  0.249719  0.284734  0.171977  0.157868  0.025336  
19  0.206942  0.249719  0.284734  0.171977  0.157868
```

Comment: thanks, i know it's a super simple question, but to me, i just start python 2 weeks ago, and I've tried the whole day on this tiny small question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use assign and shift:

```
df.assign(**{'{}-D'.format(i): df['1-D'].shift(i-1) for i in range(2,11)})
```

A bit explanation:

```
{'{}-D'.format(i): df['1-D'].shift(i-1) for i in range(2,11)}
```

Builds a dict with column names as keys and column series as values. The ** operator unpacks the dictionary keys and values and feed them as parameters to the assign function. It's the same as calling:

```
df.assign(2-D=xxx, 3-D=yyy...)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is such a short and complex code, and very beautiful! I gonna split it into several steps for better understanding!

Comment: Thanks for your editing, i can understand this part: {'{}-D'.format(i): df['1-D'].shift(i-1) for i in range(2,11)}, but i cannot understand what ** means here?